# Squaring numbers in array, finding the sum and the biggest number

Tags: c++

I have a task to square all the elements of array, separate them with ",", then find a sum of the squared array and find the biggest number of it. I managed to square them and find the sum, but I can't find the biggest number and the program is also printing "," at the end of new array.
This is my code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <algorithm>
using namespace std;

int main() {
  int a[10];
int n,sum=0,kiek=0,max=a[0];;
cin>>n;

for(int i=0;i<n;i++)
{cin>>a[i];

a[i]*=a[i];
sum=sum+a[i];
}
 for (int i = 0 ; i < n ; i++) 
     {   cout <<a[i] << ","; }
     cout<<endl ;
cout<<"suma " <<sum;
cout<<endl;

for(int i=0;i<10;i++)
    {if(max<a[i])
        {
            max = a[i];
        } 
    }
  cout<<"max "<<max;
return 0;
}
```

[This is the screenshot of my program result when I run it](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sjAIl.png)

Comment: I think you meant to initialize max to 0 not a[0]

Comment: `max=a[0]` sets `max` to some garbage value that was stored in memory at this address. In your example run it was 4197008. As long as the input isn't bigger than that value `max` won't change it's value.

Comment: @ThomasSablik Please answer in an answer, not in a comment.

Comment: xdarkestshadow, what is the maximum number of inputs to be processed? If it is not 10, then you have a bigger problem in your code which you have not yet noticed.

Comment: @Yunnosch, the maximum number of inputs is 10.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```cpp
#include <iostream>
#include <algorithm>

using namespace std;

int main() {
    int a[10];
    int n, sum = 0;  // Remove some unused variables

    // Input //
    cin >> n;
    for(int i = 0; i < n; i++){
        cin >> a[i];
        a[i] *= a[i];
        sum += a[i];
    }


    // List a[] and sum //
    for (int i = 0 ; i < n - 1 ; i++) {
        cout << a[i] << ", ";
    }
    cout << a[n - 1] << endl; // Just for a little beauty
    cout << "suma " << sum << endl;


    // Find Max //
    int max = a[0];  // max should be declared there, 
                     // because a[0] has not entered data at the first
    for(int i = 0; i < n; i++) {  // use n, not 10
        if(a[i] > max){
            max = a[i];
        } 
    }
    cout << "max " << max;


    return 0;
}
```

Unchecked.

Please add indents, spaces and comment, this is a good habit.

Answer (score 0):

Comment : If you are going to get the size of the array at run-time, it is better to use STL containers or pointers.  Your issue lies here :

```
---> for(int i=0;i<10;i++)
         {if(max<a[i])
```

Good luck.

Comment: Any problem caused by this would also be likely to be causes by the problem mentioned in the comment. Pick that up and you have a decent answer.